# FB api graphql : Calculate the number of messages with friends in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the fb graph api to get total messages with each friends.
I was looking at an app and found them doing the following (by seeing the XHR and fetch request in Network F12 developer)
Step 1: they get the token from link:

```
https://m.facebook.com/composer/ocelot/async_loader/?publisher=feed
```

Step 2: get the friend list from api:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/friends?
```

Step 3: get the total message with each friend by api:

[api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7fEI.png)

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChpqH.png)

I am having the problem at the step 3, my code

```
var form = new FormData;
form.append("fb_dtsg", {fb_dtsg:I took in step 1});
form.append("q", "viewer(){message_threads{nodes{thread_key{thread_fbid,other_user_id},messages_count,thread_type,updated_time_precise}}}");
fetch("https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql/", {
    body : form,
    headers : {
      accept : "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    method : "POST"
}).then(function(e) {
    return e.text();
}).then(function(savedC){
      /** savedC IS EMPTY */
});
```

The value of "saveC" is not as expected, it is empty.
Can anyone help me know where i am going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: There is no way to do what you want using any official APIs, access to user messages has been removed a while ago.

Comment: Hi @CBroe , I want to count the total number of messages in my chats with my fb friends. if you see the picture I attached , they can do that.

Comment: That’s not using any API that you are _supposed_ to use then.

Comment: Thanks , but why I see this api in Network tab in the developer tools?

Comment: Because the website must load the data from somewhere. That doesn’t mean you are supposed to use it for your own purposes.